# Quarkus 403 Forbidden response

Tags: kotlin, quarkus

I have a simple Quarkus application written in Kotlin. In my application.properties file I have:

```
# Add authentication
quarkus.http.auth.proactive=false
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.paths=/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.policy=authenticated

# Allow some paths
quarkus.http.auth.permission.allowed.paths=/health/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.allowed.policy=permit
quarkus.http.auth.permission.allowed.methods=GET
```

I'm basically trying to authenticate all paths except /health

I tried creating a custom **HttpAuthenticationMechanism** as I need a custom logic for authenticating.

```
@ApplicationScoped
class SecurityCustomAuth : HttpAuthenticationMechanism {

override fun authenticate(
    context: RoutingContext?,
    identityProviderManager: IdentityProviderManager?
): Uni<SecurityIdentity?>? {
    logger.info("====== custom auth")
    //some logic
}
```

When I try to call any URL except /health I get a 403 error message and the custom auth method is never called. Why?

EDIT: It seems that it has nothing to do with my custom auth mechanism, even if I remove it completely, I still get a 403 response code with the properties mentioned above instead of 401.

Comment: Hi, `authenticated` policy requires a security identity with any or no roles at all, it is similar to `@PermitAll`. 
It is enforced at the Role-Based-Access-Control level and this is why you see `403`. It is only the authentication mechanisms which can force 401.

I can see why it can be confusing - but if you think about it, the policy alone can not get the users authenticated, the mechanism must enforce it. However, not sure why your custom mechanism is not called. Can you please open a Quarkus issue, if possible with a reproducer ? We have a test authentication mechanism called in tests

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply, what is even weirder but maybe helps with the debugging is that if I add quarkus-smallrye-jwt and jwt-build to the project, my auth mechanism is called and it works as expected.. except that 1. it feels wrong to add these dependencies and 2. now /health also calls the auth even if proactive is false, which my understanding is it shouldn't.

Comment: Can you open the issue and explain how you implement your custom mechanism ? There might be some issues if the credential transport is custom and it is only a single mechanism

Comment: Actually, your comment about the credential transport helped me debug the issue. There were no identity providers available for the AuthenticationRequest I was using. I was not actually using the IdentityProvider, I was just authenticating directly from the custom HttpAuthenticationMechanism, but nevertheless, it was required and I didn't know. For the moment, I'm returning an emptySet() credential type, but I should implement my own IdentityProvider in the future. Thanks so much!

Comment: Np, please consider opening the doc enhancement requests